# How to send value from RadioButton selected from one class to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, radio-button, sender

I have a MainClass.m which holds the UI of scrollView and UIView, then I have a different class for scrollView implementation.

I have a RadioButton in my scrollView and when clicked on it, I need to pass the selectedValue to MainClass.m which has a "Continue" button & onClick of that continue button the value should be retrieved.

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)radioButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
        if (self.radioBtn.isSelected ==  true) {
            [self.radioBtn setSelected:NO];
            self.productValue = [[ViewController2 sharedInstance] stringValue:self.productId];
            [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }else {
            [self.radioBtn setSelected:YES];
            self.productValue = [[ViewController2 sharedInstance] stringValue:self.productId];
            [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }

//This method is in viewController2
- (NSString*) stringValue:(NSString *) productValue{
    self.strVal= productValue;//I get the value here
    return productValue;
}

//This method is in viewController2
- (IBAction)productCellBtnAction:(UIButton*)sender {

    NSLog(@"strVal :%@",self.strVal);
//I get self.strVal = null
}
```

Comment: Either you can pass value with parameter from one view controller to another OR you can use Delegate to achieve the same.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Do you have the property object of scrollView and UIView in MainClass.h?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have added the code

Comment: @BhavikModi I tried to pass but I get null value